# intellij Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found. but test is ok

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

i'm wonder that i can see this error(Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found. )

this is my code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;


@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class)
public class HomeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("home"))
                .andExpect(content().string(
                        containsString("Welcome to...")));
    }
}
```

this test code run successfully. but mockMVC shows error about autowring.

how to delete this error?

please anyone help.

i'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition), java, spring, junit5.

thanks

Comment: Please prepare and provide a minimal project sample reproducing the problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same editor error with 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) version. You can ignore that specific point of error adding @SuppressWarnings tag:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

This can be generated too with editor assistance:
Right click over the variable > Show context actions > Inspection 'Incorrect injection point autowiring in Spring bean components' options > Suppress for field

Another way is to update the editor. Currently i'm using 2022.2.2 and the error    is not detected.

Comment: Although this works for me, using `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` above the test class also removes the warning.

Comment: @GaidinD Your annotation is not working with the author's version  You can check it easily with JetBrains Toolbox upgrading and deactivating the IDE https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/toolbox/

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` already has `@AutoconfigureMockMvc`. As answered above it could be a intellij bug. 
But I am not facing it now.

Answer (score 0):

To use MockMvc in your test class, you should add the @AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation along with @SpringBootTest. This annotation tells Spring to auto-configure the MockMvc instance for your tests. Here's the corrected example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class YourApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        // Check if the ApplicationContext has been loaded successfully
        assertNotNull(mockMvc, "MockMvc bean should be initialized")
        
        // You can add more assertions as needed
        // For example, assert that specific controllers have been created
    }
}
```